# OData Binding in TableSelectDialog SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to do odata binding on tableselectdialog. For some reasons, I am finding it hard to make a fragment using SAP WEB IDE so I did not use fragments for the dialog and just made the dialog on the controller. Assuming that most of the properties of table can be seen on tableselectdialog, I was expecting that I will not encounter any errors. I was able to bind my odata on a table. But when I implemented a tableselectdialog, the data binding doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me solve this error. Below is my code.

A combobox calls the event press with the method handleAddressType. The odata I'm using is /sap/opu/odata/srmnxp/UTIL

```
handleAddressType: function(oEvent) {
    alert(oEvent.oSource.getSelectedKey());
    var selectedAddressKey = oEvent.oSource.getSelectedKey();
    var otableSelectDialog = new sap.m.TableSelectDialog("tableSelectD", {
        noDataText: "No Address Found",
        title: "Select Address",
        columns: [
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "AddressNo"
                })
            }),
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "Name"
                })
            }),
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "City"
                })
            }),
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "Country"
                })
            })
        ],
        items: {
            path: "/",
            template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                cells: [
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{UTIL>AddressNo}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{UTIL>Name}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{UTIL>City}"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{UTIL>Country}"
                    })
                ]
            })
        }
    });
    otableSelectDialog.bindAggregation("items", "UTIL>/ShipToAddressCollection?$filter=Addrtype%20eq%20%27" + selectedAddressKey + "%27",
        new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{UTIL>AddressNo}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{UTIL>Name}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{UTIL>City}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{UTIL>Country}"
                })
            ]
        }));
    otableSelectDialog.open();
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Where is the named model "UTIL" set? Is it on the view, the Component, on a control? Is it set via manifest.json or manually? If manually, please show how exactly...

Furthermore, your binding path looks a little strange:

```
path : "/",
```

What EntitySet is "/" supposed to be? Furthermore, you are using the named model "UTIL" in the rest of the code which is also missing in the binding path. So I guess the binding path should look something like this in your case:

```
path : "UTIL>/MyEntitySet",
```

Of course you have to replace "/MyEntitySet" with whatever fits in your case. This only works if the service at "sap/opu/odata/srmnxp/UTIL" is a named model "UTIL". However, this "UTIL" named model has nothing to do with the "UTIL" in the URL string "sap/opu/odata/srmnxp/UTIL".

Comment: My Util Odata is set in component.js. I'm assuming since I will bind the the path viw bindAggregation, it does not matter what I will put on path since it will be replace anyway.

Comment: Actually it is on configuration.js 

{
                name: "UTIL",
                masterCollection: "ShipToAddressCollection",
                serviceUrl: URI("/sap/opu/odata/srmnxp/UTIL/").directory(),
                isDefault: false,
                mockedDataSource: "/srm.shoppingcart.create/model/metadata.xml"
            },

Comment: @melai You can bind multiple models at the same time, that's why you name them (UTIL in this case). If you've set a name, you have to use it. Otherwise the framework will look for a model without a name (the global model).

Comment: @Nabi `path: "/"` can refer to an unnamed Model that consists solely of an array of objects (unlikely in an OData context, but very likely if you deal with plain JSON). See http://jsbin.com/tobifiqoto/2/edit?html,output

Comment: @Marc I have used changed the path to this UTIL>/ShipToAddressCollection?$filter=Addrtype%20eq%20%27C%27 this was what I was using to bind my table before. Supposedly, the code should get the data if I also use it as my binding path for TableSelectDialog

Comment: @Marc As I expect that the model is an ODataModel the path "/" is invalid, as it does not refer the EntitySet.

Comment: @melai So you are now using path: "UTIL>/ShipToAddressCollection?$filter=Addrtype%20eq%20%27C%27", right? Simply use path: "UTIL>/ShipToAddressCollection" instead, don't use odata option directly in the path! Does it actually work now or not?

Comment: @Nabi. Yes I am using UTIL>/ShipToAddressCollection?$filter=Addrtype%20eq%20%27C%27. I changed it to UTIL>/ShipToAddressCollection but still no data :(